# Updating database tables using spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Why doesn't Apache Spark offer the capability to update specific columns of a database table?

I attempted to update a PostgreSQL table using basic Spark read and write operations but I was not able to it. I had to pass complete update query to database in order to perform update operation.